# Best practice for making async API calls in node using fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm building an app in nodeJS, express and MySQL where I'm collecting data from several different API:s using node fetch, one which has a limit of 200 calls per 5 minute.

In order to update my database completely I need to essentially run calls to this API nonstop,
currently I'm trying to stay within the boundaries of the limit by using a sleep in a for loop/foreach.

The problem is that each request can vary in time and it just seems like I could make the calls more effective rather than constantly sleeping the same amount of time for each request. I was wondering if there's a better way to do this? I've been thinking about making e.g 199 calls async and then waiting exactly 5 minutes, and then repeating it.. but I have no idea how.

Couldn't find a thread on this but please do link one if there's a good answer already.
Answers are much appreciated, and if you have other feedback please do let me know!

````
  for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    try {
      let id = IdCollection[i];
      let resultFromApiCall = await datafetcher.MakeApiCall(id);

      await sleep(2000);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error in api-calls" + error);
    }
  }```
````

Comment: I think the optimal solution depends on what you're fetching here. I don't know if there needs to be that delay between each `fetch` or not, because I don't know what you're fetching.

Comment: If you absolutely need to make that many requests perhaps you should look into WebSockets (https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a matter of taste here.

I'd make all allowed requests at once and then wait until the 5min interval is over.

```js
  // constants to define the restrictions
  const restrictionCalls = 5;
  const restrictionTime = 300000; // 5 * 60 * 1000

  let throttleTimer = Date.now(); // when did we start this interval?
  let throttleCounter = 0; // how many calls did we make in this interval?

  for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    try {
      let id = IdCollection[i];
      throttleCounter++;
      let resultFromApiCall = await datafetcher.MakeApiCall(id);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error in api-calls" + error);
    }

    if(throttleCounter === restrictionCalls) {
      const timePassed = Date.now() - throttleTimer;
      const waitTime = restrictionTime - timePassed;
      if(waitTime > 0) await sleep(waitTime);

      // reset
      throttleTimer = Date.now();
      throttleCounter = 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Trying this out and it seems to work great with some minor tweaks. Brilliant :)